# Can't install coc-definitions?

Tags: vim, text-editor, coc.nvim

I'm using neovim and installed the `coc` plugin, I have the following in my `.vimrc`

```
Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}

let g:coc_global_extensions = ['coc-emmet', 'coc-css', 'coc-html', 'coc-    json', 'coc-tsserver', 'coc-definition']
nmap <silent> gd <Plug>(coc-definition)
```

Strangely enough, the `go to definition` works, but I get the error below any time I start Vim.

> [coc.nvim] Error on install coc-definition: Error: Invalid response from htt
>   ps://registry.npmjs.org/coc-definition: 404

Answer (score 0):

`coc-definitions` is not a global extension. Remove it from the `g:coc_global_extensions` list.

Comment: And? So? What should you do instead?